# Do I needto apply a new B1/B2 visa if my fathers name is rectified on new passport?

Tags: visas, usa, passports

I have recently been issued a B1/B2 visa and an Indian national, but I have applied for a new passport to rectify my fathers name and also include my new address. My personal details will have no change and will match with the printed visa.

Do I still need to apply for a new visa on the new passport in such case?

Answer (score 2):

If your own name, birth date, and other personal details are the same on your new passport as on your US visa, then you can continue to use it. You only need to carry both passports when you travel to the USA. The US does not pay attention to the parents' name and address on passports, only your own identity details.